# Scala substring(i, outOfBoundsNum) sometimes ok in Fiddle, but not in production code?

Tags: scala

I noticed that this:

```
val word = "My word"
println(word.substring(0,1000))
```

Works just fine in a Scala Fiddle: [here](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/r2RGVeS/0)

But it throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception when running in production. Why is this allowed in the Fiddle, is it a Scala versioning? I'm testing this in Scala 2.12 for my production code.

Comment: I suspect it's a JVM vs JS difference. See the "Undefined behavior" section of http://www.scala-js.org/doc/semantics.html; `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` are both listed.

Comment: That's definitely it - don't trust ScalaFiddle. Use a Scala worksheet instead!

Comment: Or use the REPL.

Comment: The REPL is Satan's toolbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a JVM vs JS difference. See the "Undefined behavior" section of http://www.scala-js.org/doc/semantics.html; `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` are both listed.